# python logger loggin twice

Tags: python, logging, flask, werkzeug

I have a simple flask app which is supposed to log to console. My issue is that it is logging twice to console.

I have following logging config:

```
root = logging.getLogger()
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
ch = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s | src="%(name)s" | lvl="%(levelname)s" | msg="%(message)s"')
ch.setFormatter(formatter)
ch.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root.addHandler(ch)
#werkzeug disable werkzeug logs
werkzeug_logger = logging.getLogger('werkzeug')
werkzeug_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

Console output:

```
INFO:auth:Starting oauth flow
2017-06-08 14:16:08,494 | src="auth" | lvl="INFO" | msg="Starting oauth flow"
```

Comment: How are you actually using your logger; for that matter, which logger are you using, `root` or `werkzeug_logger`?

Comment: root. I want to stop werkzeug logger.

Comment: werkzeug is using the default logger sometimes (google it up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to determine how many handlers do `root` has:

```
print(len(root.handlers))
```

I guess you have more then one handlers. To avoid this you can add a handler if there are no other handlers:

```
if not root.handlers:
    root.addHandler(...)
```

You can remove all the handlers from a logger:

```
for x in root.handlers.copy():
    root.removeHandler(x)
```

Comment: yes, it had an extra handler attached which I removed and it works as expected now. Thanks!